# Перестала кликать мышка в Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, драйвер

Установил Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, все работало нормально кроме разрешения экрана - оно было 640х или меньше. Затем установил пакет обновлений и драйвера на видеокарту nvidia (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-settings , затем sudo nvidia-xconfig). Перезапустил ПК. Сейчас клавиатура работает, а мышка двигается, но может кликать только внутри окон приложений (firefox, центр обновлений и т.д.), а сама система ее как бы не видит (иконки не загораются при наведении, на клики не реагирует).

Пол Гугла перелопатил - вроде преблема не только у меня, но какого-то конкретного решения (понятного мне) не нашел. Систему переустановил дважды - та же фигня. При этом в обычном Ubuntu 15.10 и Win 7 все работает нормально. В Линуксе не разбираюсь, буду признателен за конретные команды в терминал.

Comment: нашел решение!!! снес дрова nvidia и все заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов - забить.
Если ты пользуешься Gnome, а не Unity на убунте - то вполне логично поставить другой дистр. Например ту-же Fedora. Просто по тому что Fedora любит Gnome, и это ее первоочередное DE. Хотя там Wayland, и его вроде еще не подружили с Нвидией. Просто там Wayland даже в SDDM.

А если с Ubuntu бороться, то метод проб и ошибок.. "Систему переустановил дважды - та же фигня" это типа в дефолтной системе такое? если только после переустановки драйвера, так проблема в дровах же.

В убунте есть специально графический способ установки дров. Ищи в программах "driver-что-то-то-там" и там экспериментируй с версиями дров. Там около 4х вариантов будет для твоей видеокарты. Я бы сказал, что это самый правильный способ установки дров.